# How to Use /etc/hosts on FreeBSD 13.1

Tags: domain-name-system, freebsd

This is a plain vanilla fresh install of FreeBSD 13.1. The resolv.conf file is as follows and Unbound is not enabled.

```
nameserver 192.0.2.1
```

DNS resolution on the local machine is ignoring `/etc/hosts`. What is missing from the configuration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly your assumption that DNS includes entries from `/etc/hosts`.

All **commands/tools designed to test DNS**  such as  `dig` ,  `nslookup` , `host` and such **only query DNS servers** and by default use the DNS server that is configured in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

To test how the C library resolver works, and all programs that use the system resolver routines who do honour [`/etc/nsswitch.conf`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=nsswitch.conf&sektion=5&n=1) precedence and which normally prefer the hosts file over DNS, requires testing with something like [`getent`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=getent) :

```
getent hosts some.hostname.in.etc.hosts
getent hosts IP.in.etc.hosts
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.